# BigCommerce Stencil CLI

Tags: bigcommerce, stencil-compiler

I'm new to Stencil CLI. I recently install the same and noticed after some digging that the .stencil file is now deprecated but have no idea how to use it's replacements, which I assume is config.stencil.json and secrets.stencil.json. I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwrVN5QrEZY&t=20s

Anyone with some idea on how use them to create custom pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would follow the same exact setup, just put the page template in the config.stencil.json file.

This file might look something like this:

```
{
  "normalStoreUrl": "https://store-abcde12345.mybigcommerce.com",
  "port": 3000,
  "customLayouts": {
    "brand": {},
    "category": {},
    "page": {
      "about-us": "/about-us"
    },
    "product": {}
  }
}
```

The secrets.stencil.json file only contains the API token.

```
{
  "accessToken": "tokenhere"
}
```